# Trying to get a section to display on right of web page (HTML)

Tags: html, css

We have a Daddyleagues account for our Madden league. It allows you to edit with HTML, your home page. I am having an issue with some content, being displayed at the very bottom, left side, instead of starting from top, on the right side. 
Take a look here: http://www.daddyleagues.com/maddenhub   Notice if you scroll to the bottom. Everything starting with NFC Playoff Race and below that, I want to display top right, the opposite of where AFC Playoff Race is.

Also, I dont know why, but everything is italicized font for some reason and havent been able figure that out either. Any help would be appreciated.

Daddyleagues has Layout divided into a few sections. We use League Header and League Homepage

League Header code:

```
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/o4zwSIb.jpg">

<link rel="stylesheet"
 href="https://9cb1ad0ddfa4639c452deac616a4da79ba538f1d.googledrive.com/host/0BxrpWnd_UZ7leDFJM1pOVy1xNzQ/SOSDL.css">
<div class="headerWrapper">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12"></div>
<div class="col-xs-12">
<i =""><img src="http://i.imgur.com/nPDV5ja.png"
 usemap="#teams" border="0" width="960"><map
 name="Teams">
<area shape="RECT" coords="20, 10, 60, 37"
 href="/maddenhub/team/BUF" target="_self" title="Bills">
<area shape="RECT" coords="64, 10, 104, 37"
 href="/maddenhub/team/MIA" target="_self"
 title="Dolphins">
<area shape="RECT" coords="108, 10, 148, 37"
 href="/maddenhub/team/NE" target="_self" title="Patriots">
<area shape="RECT" coords="152, 10, 192, 37"
 href="/maddenhub/team/NYJ" target="_self" title="Jets">
<area shape="RECT" coords="203, 10, 243, 37"
 href="/maddenhub/team/BAL" target="_self" title="Ravens">
<area shape="RECT" coords="247, 10, 287, 37"
 href="/maddenhub/team/CIN" target="_self" title="Bengals">
<area shape="RECT" coords="291, 10, 331, 37"
 href="/maddenhub/team/CLE" target="_self" title="Browns">
<area shape="RECT" coords="335, 10, 375, 37"
 href="/maddenhub/team/PIT" target="_self"
 title="Steelers">
<area shape="RECT" coords="20, 44, 60, 71"
 href="/maddenhub/team/HOU" target="_self" title="Texans">
<area shape="RECT" coords="64, 44, 104, 71"
 href="/maddenhub/team/IND" target="_self" title="Colts">
<area shape="RECT" coords="108, 44, 148, 71"
 href="/maddenhub/team/JAC" target="_self" title="Jaguars">
<area shape="RECT" coords="152, 44, 192, 71"
 href="/maddenhub/team/TEN" target="_self" title="Titans">
<area shape="RECT" coords="203, 44, 243, 71"
 href="/maddenhub/team/DEN" target="_self" title="Broncos">
<area shape="RECT" coords="247, 44, 287, 71"
 href="/maddenhub/team/KC" target="_self" title="Chiefs">
<area shape="RECT" coords="291, 44, 331, 71"
 href="/maddenhub/team/OAK" target="_self" title="Raiders">
<area shape="RECT" coords="335, 44, 375, 71"
 href="/maddenhub/team/SD" target="_self" title="Chargers">
<area shape="RECT" coords="586, 10, 626, 37"
 href="/maddenhub/team/DAL" target="_self" title="Cowboys">
<area shape="RECT" coords="630, 10, 670, 37"
 href="/maddenhub/team/NYG" target="_self" title="Giants">
<area shape="RECT" coords="674, 10, 714, 37"
 href="/maddenhub/team/PHI" target="_self" title="Eagles">
<area shape="RECT" coords="718, 10, 758, 37"
 href="/maddenhub/team/WAS" target="_self"
 title="Redskins">
<area shape="RECT" coords="769, 10, 809, 37"
 href="/maddenhub/team/CHI" target="_self" title="Bears">
<area shape="RECT" coords="813, 10, 853, 37"
 href="/maddenhub/team/DET" target="_self" title="Lions">
<area shape="RECT" coords="857, 10, 897, 37"
 href="/maddenhub/team/GB" target="_self" title="Packers">
<area shape="RECT" coords="901, 10, 941, 37"
 href="/maddenhub/team/MIN" target="_self" title="Vikings">
<area shape="RECT" coords="586, 44, 626, 71"
 href="/maddenhub/team/ATL" target="_self" title="Falcons">
<area shape="RECT" coords="630, 44, 670, 71"
 href="/maddenhub/team/CAR" target="_self"
 title="Panthers">
<area shape="RECT" coords="674, 44, 714, 71"
 href="/maddenhub/team/NO" target="_self" title="Saints">
<area shape="RECT" coords="718, 44, 758, 71"
 href="/maddenhub/team/TB" target="_self"
 title="Buccaneers">
<area shape="RECT" coords="769, 44, 809, 71"
 href="/maddenhub/team/ARI" target="_self"
 title="Cardinals">
<area shape="RECT" coords="813, 44, 853, 71"
 href="/maddenhub/team/SEA" target="_self"
 title="Seahawks">
<area shape="RECT" coords="857, 44, 897, 71"
 href="/maddenhub/team/SF" target="_self" title="49ers">
<area shape="RECT" coords="901, 44, 941, 71"
 href="/maddenhub/team/STL" target="_self" title="Rams">
</map>


<style type="text/css">

</div>



</style>
```

League Homepage:

```
   <div class="maincontent">

<div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12">
<div class="panel panel-gir">
</div>
<div class="panel-body">


</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="row standings">
<div class="col-xs-6">
<div class="panel panel-afc standings">
<div class="panel-heading">AFC Standings</div>
<div class="panel-body">
<div id="afc-east-container"></div>
<div id="afc-north-container"></div>
<div id="afc-south-container"></div>
<div id="afc-west-container"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6">
<div class="panel panel-nfc standings">
<div class="panel-heading">NFC Standings</div>
<div class="panel-body">
<div id="nfc-east-container"></div>
<div id="nfc-north-container"></div>
<div id="nfc-south-container"></div>
<div id="nfc-west-container"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-3">
<div class="panel panel-afc nopad playoffs">
<div class="panel-heading">AFC Playoff Race</div>
<div class="panel-body">
<div id="afc-playoff-container"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-afc nopad stats">
<div class="panel-heading">Offensive Leaders</div>
<div class="panel-body">
<div id="s-passing-leaders-container"></div>
<div id="s-rushing-leaders-container"></div>
<div id="s-receiving-leaders-container"></div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- POWER RANKINGS -->
<div class="panel panel-afc nopad rankings">
<div class="panel-heading">Power Rankings</div>
<div class="panel-body">
<a href="http://daddyleagues.com/maddenhub/standing/ranking"></a>
<div id="powerrankings-container"></div>
</div>
<div class="panel-footer"><a href="http://daddyleagues.com/maddenhub   /standing/ranking">Click Here For Full Rankings</a></div>
</div>

<!--xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx enter other blocks above this line-->
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6">
<!-- ADVANCE COUNTDOWN -->
<div class="panel panel-gir nopad countdown">
<div class="panel-heading">Advance Countdown</div>
<div class="panel-body">
<div id="advanceclock-container"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-gir nopad gotw">
<div class="panel-heading">Game of the Week</div>
<div class="panel-body">
<div id="gameoftheweek-container"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-gir nopad potw">
<div class="panel-heading">Padders of the Week</div>
<div class="panel-body">
<div class="panel nopad panel-player">
<div class="panel-heading">Offensive</div>
<div class="panel-body">
<div id="oplayeroftheweek-container"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="panel nopad panel-player">
<div class="panel-heading">Defensive</div>
<div class="panel-body">
<div id="dplayeroftheweek-container"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-gir nopad twitter">
<div class="panel-heading">League Twitter</div>
<div class="panel-body">
<div id="storyline-container"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-gir nopad twitter">
<div class="panel-heading">Media Twitter</div>
<div class="panel-body">
<div id="tweets-container"></div>
</div>

<!-- Begin Daddyleagues shoutbox-->
<iframe src="http://www.daddyleagues.com/MaddenHub/shoutbox"  height="600px"  scrolling="no" width="100%" ></iframe>
<!-- shoutbox-->
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="hmPortlet">
<div class="hmPortletDecoration">
<div class="hmPortletTitle" style="color:#ffffff;text-align:center">Around The League</div>
</div>
<div class="hmPortletContent">
<div id="news-stream-container"></div>
</div>
</div><!--end of newswire portlet -->

</div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-3">
<div class="panel panel-nfc nopad playoffs">
<div class="panel-heading">NFC Playoff Race</div>
<div class="panel-body">
<div id="nfc-playoff-container"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-nfc nopad stats">
<div class="panel-heading">Defensive Leaders</div>
<div class="panel-body">
<div id="s-defense-leaders-container"></div>
<div id="s-defenseint-leaders-container"></div>
<div id="s-sacks-leaders-container"></div>
</div>

<div class="hmPortlet">
<div class="hmPortletDecoration">
<div class="hmPortletTitle" style="color:#ffffff;text-align:center">Transactions Log</div>
</div>
<div class="hmPortletContent">
<div id="transactions-container"></div>
</div>
</div><!--end of frontoffice portlet -->
```

Here is the CSS code:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

@font-face{font-family:'NFLEndzoneSansCondMedium';src:url('http://i.nflcdn.com/static/site/7.1/img/fonts/endzone-sans/medium-cond.eot')}
@font-face{font-family:'NFLEndzoneSansCondMedium';src:url('//:') format('no404'),
url('http://i.nflcdn.com/static/site/7.1/img/fonts/endzone-sans/medium-cond.eot?#iefix') format('eot'),
url('http://i.nflcdn.com/static/site/7.1/img/fonts/endzone-sans/medium-cond.woff') format('woff'),
url('http://i.nflcdn.com/static/site/7.1/img/fonts/endzone-sans/medium-cond.ttf') format('truetype'),
url('http://i.nflcdn.com/static/site/7.1/img/fonts/endzone-sans/medium-cond.svg#webfont9DqcIwJf') format('svg');font-weight:normal;font-style:normal}

@font-face{font-family:'NFLEndzoneSlabBold';src:url('http://i.nflcdn.com/static/site/7.1/img/fonts/endzone-slab/bold.eot')}
@font-face{font-family:'NFLEndzoneSlabBold';src:url('//:') format('no404'),
url('http://i.nflcdn.com/static/site/7.1/img/fonts/endzone-slab/bold.eot?iefix') format('eot'),
url('http://i.nflcdn.com/static/site/7.1/img/fonts/endzone-slab/bold.woff') format('woff'),
url('http://i.nflcdn.com/static/site/7.1/img/fonts/endzone-slab/bold.ttf') format('truetype'),
url('http://i.nflcdn.com/static/site/7.1/img/fonts/endzone-slab/bold.svg#EndzoneSlab-Bold') format('svg');font-weight:normal;font-style:normal}

@font-face{font-family:'NFLEndzoneTechBold';src:url('http://i.nflcdn.com/static/site/7.1/img/fonts/endzone-tech/bold.eot')}
@font-face{font-family:'NFLEndzoneTechBold';src:url('//:') format('no404'),
url('http://i.nflcdn.com/static/site/7.1/img/fonts/endzone-tech/bold.eot') format('eot'),
url('http://i.nflcdn.com/static/site/7.1/img/fonts/endzone-tech/bold.woff') format('woff'),
url('http://i.nflcdn.com/static/site/7.1/img/fonts/endzone-tech/bold.ttf') format('truetype'),
url('http://i.nflcdn.com/static/site/7.1/img/fonts/endzone-tech/bold.svg#EndzoneTech-Bold') format('svg');font-weight:normal;font-style:normal}



/***** Daddyleagues Layout *****/


#PageContent {
    border:2px solid #a1a1a1;
    padding:10px 10px; 
    background:#dddddd; 
    height: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 10px 10px #000000;
    border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:25px; /* Firefox 3.6 and earlier */
}

#hmPageWrapper {
    margin:0 auto;

    border:2px solid #ffffff;
background:#ffffff;
height: auto;

    }

.home-column {
  float:left;
  margin-right:0px;
}

.home-left-column {
    width:212px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.home-middle-column {
    width:474px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    margin-left:6px;
}

.home-right-column {
    width:212px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    margin-left:6px;
}

img{max-width:100%;height:auto;vertical-align:middle;border:0;-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;}



.hmPortletDecoration  {
    border: 1px #606060 solid;
    padding: 0px 0px;
    background: #000000 url('http://i1208.photobucket.com/albums/cc380/NDAlum/NFLfiller_zpsudwwfw3r.png');
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.hmPortletContent{
    border: 2px #242323 solid;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    color: #00000;
    font-family: NFLEndzoneTechBold, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: bold;
            border-radius: 0px 0px 7px 7px; 
-moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 7px 7px; 
-webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 7px 7px; 
}

.hmPortletContent2{
    border: 2px #242323 solid;
    height: 140px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    color: #00000;
    font-family: NFLEndzoneTechBold, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: bold;
            border-radius: 0px 0px 7px 7px; 
-moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 7px 7px; 
-webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 7px 7px; 
}
.hmPortletContent3{
    border: 2px #242323 solid;
    height: 340px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    color: #00000;
    font-family: NFLEndzoneTechBold, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: bold;
            border-radius: 0px 0px 7px 7px; 
-moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 7px 7px; 
-webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 7px 7px; 
}
.visitor{
    margin-left:55px;
}

.hmPortletContentPadding{
    padding: 2px;
}



/***** Daddy GOW*****/
.gameoftheweek {
position:relative;
    width:100%;
    line-height:30px;
    border-bottom:0px;
    background: #000 center center;
font-family: NFLEndzoneTechBold, sans-serif;
}

.gameoftheweek .cfm-table tr td.cfm-at {
    width:60px;
    background-image:url('http://www.easports.com/madden-nfl/connected-franchise/bundles/maddenccm/images/game-details-at.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:center;
}

.gameoftheweek .cfm-table tr td .score {
    color:#FFF;
}

.cfm-table {
    color:#FFF;
}

.gameoftheweek .ng-scope { background-position:100% 50%; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:75%; height:140px; margin:0 10px 0 0;} 
.gameoftheweek .align-right.ng-scope { background-position:0% 50%; background-repeat:no-repeat; margin:0px 0px 0px 10px;} 
.gameoftheweek .team { position:absolute; bottom:0; left:0; font-family: NFLEndzoneTechBold, sans-serif;display:none; font-size:14px}
.gameoftheweek .team i { font-family: NFLEndzoneTechBold, sans-serif; font-style:normal; }


/* Daddy League Overrides */
.adsense:first-of-type { display:none;}
#daddyleagues-navbar { margin-bottom:20px;}
.maincontent { padding-top:5px;}
.headerWrapper { width:960px;}
.container { width: 960px; background:none;}
.content {background:#fff;}

html { background:#011226; }
body { background:url('http://i1208.photobucket.com/albums/cc380/NDAlum/SOSbackground_zps7mpfoxc6.jpg') repeat center top;}
.scorelist {background: #F0F0F0;width: 100%;}
.scorelist .yui3-scorestrip-tile {font-family: NFLEndzoneTechBold, sans-serif;}

.yui3-scorestrip-tile-visitor-wins .yui3-scorestrip-tile-visitor, .yui3-scorestrip-tile-home-wins .yui3-scorestrip-tile-home { color:#222;}



    #player-profile { position:relative;}
    #player-team-overlay-container { margin:0;}

/* Bootstrap Overrides */
.panel-gir .panel-heading, .panel-afc .panel-heading, .panel-nfc .panel-heading  { text-transform:uppercase; padding:10px;}
.panel-gir .panel-body, .panel-afc .panel-body, .panel-nfc .panel-body  { padding:10px; background:url("http://i1208.photobucket.com/albums/cc380/NDAlum/Whitefiller_zpsi42dlfl0.png");}
.panel-gir .panel-footer, .panel-afc .panel-footer, .panel-nfc .panel-footer  { font-size: 10px; padding: 4px 10px;}

.panel-gir .panel-heading a, .panel-afc .panel-heading a, .panel-nfc .panel-heading a,
.panel-gir .panel-footer a, .panel-afc .panel-footer a, .panel-nfc .panel-footer a { color:#fff;}
.panel-gir .panel-heading a:hover, .panel-afc .panel-heading a:hover, .panel-nfc .panel-heading a:hover,
.panel-gir .panel-footer a:hover, .panel-afc .panel-footer a:hover, .panel-nfc .panel-footer a { color:#eee;}

.standings .panel-body { padding:0;}
.nopad .panel-body { padding:0;}

.panel-gir {border-radius:0px; border-color: #222;}
.panel-gir > .panel-heading,
.panel-gir > .panel-footer { color: #fff; text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #222; background:url("http://i1208.photobucket.com/albums/cc380/NDAlum/NFLfiller_zpsudwwfw3r.png"); border-color: #222; border-radius:0; font-family: NFLEndzoneTechBold, sans-serif;}
.panel-gir > .panel-heading + .panel-collapse > .panel-body { border-top-color: #bfbfbf;}
.panel-gir > .panel-heading .badge { color: #fff; background-color: #222;}


.panel-afc {border-radius:0px; border-color: #000000;}
.panel-afc > .panel-heading,
.panel-afc > .panel-footer  { color: #fff; text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #000000; background:url("http://i1208.photobucket.com/albums/cc380/NDAlum/AFCfiller_zpsj6v4l87f.png"); border-color: #000000; border-radius:0; font-family: NFLEndzoneTechBold, sans-serif;}
.panel-afc > .panel-heading + .panel-collapse > .panel-body { border-top-color: #000000;}
.panel-afc > .panel-heading .badge { color: #000000; background-color: #fff;}


.panel-nfc {border-radius:0px; border-color: #000000;}
.panel-nfc > .panel-heading,
.panel-nfc > .panel-footer { color: #fff; text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #000000; background:url("http://i1208.photobucket.com/albums/cc380/NDAlum/NFCfiller_zpsw4kf8oq3.png"); border-color: #000000; border-radius:0; font-family: NFLEndzoneTechBold, sans-serif;}
.panel-nfc > .panel-heading + .panel-collapse > .panel-body { border-top-color: #000000;}
.panel-nfc > .panel-heading .badge { color: #000000; background-color: #fff;}

/* Standings */
.standings .data-table1 td, .standings .data-table1 th { font-size:10px; line-height:12px; padding:0 4px;}

.standings #afc-east-container,
.standings #afc-north-container,
.standings #afc-south-container,
.standings #afc-west-container,
.standings #nfc-east-container,
.standings #nfc-north-container,
.standings #nfc-south-container,
.standings #nfc-west-container { width:25%; float:left; border-right:1px solid;}

.standings #afc-west-container, .standings #nfc-west-container { border-right:0px solid;}

.panel-afc .data-table1 .thd1 td { background:#000000;}
.standings #afc-east-container,
.standings #afc-north-container,
.standings #afc-south-container,
.standings #afc-west-container { border-color:#000000;}

.panel-nfc .data-table1 .thd1 td { background:#000000;}
.standings #nfc-east-container,
.standings #nfc-north-container,
.standings #nfc-south-container,
.standings #nfc-west-container { border-color:#000000;}


.standings img { height:12px; width:12px; margin-right:2px;}
.teamLogo { margin-right:2px;}

/* transactions */
.transactions .data-table1 td, .transactions .data-table1 th { font-size:11px; line-height:12px; padding:2px 4px;}
.transactions img { height:12px; width:12px; margin-right:2px;}

/* Countdown */
.countdownHolder { width:200px; height:auto;}
.countdownHolder .countText { color:#222; font-family: NFLEndzoneTechBold, sans-serif;}

/* Powerrankings */
#powerrankings div {display: none;}

/* Playoffs */
.playoffs .data-table1 td, .standings .data-table1 th { padding:0 4px;}

.panel-afc.playoffs td.bubble { background:#000000!important; color:#fff!important; border:none!important;}
.panel-nfc.playoffs td.bubble { background:#000000!important; color:#fff!important; border:none!important;}

/* POTW */
.playeroftheweek { margin:0;}
.panel-player { width:50%; display:block; float:left; background:none; border:none; box-shadow:none; margin-bottom:0;}
.panel-player a { color:inherit;}
.panel-player .panel-heading {color: #222;text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #ccc;background:none;;border-radius: 0;font-family: NFLEndzoneTechBold, sans-serif; padding:5px 10px 0px 10px; text-align:center;}
.panel-player .panel-body { margin:5px; padding:5px; background:none; margin-top:0; padding-top:0;}
.panel-player .avatar {width: 203px;height:203px;position:relative;background:url("http://i1208.photobucket.com/albums/cc380/NDAlum/Whitefiller_zpsi42dlfl0.png");-webkit-border-radius: 5px;-moz-border-radius: 5px;-ms-border-radius: 5px;-o-border-radius: 5px;border-radius: 5px;}
.panel-player .avatar img {width: 100%;height: 100%;position: absolute;bottom: 0;left: 0;z-index: 6;-webkit-border-radius: 5px;-moz-border-radius: 5px;-ms-border-radius: 5px;-o-border-radius: 5px;border-radius: 5px;background: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(35,35,35,0.5) 0%, rgba(153,153,153,0) 80%);background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 100%, 50% 0%, color-stop(0%, rgba(35,35,35,0.5)), color-stop(80%, rgba(153,153,153,0)));background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(35,35,35,0.5) 0%, rgba(153,153,153,0) 80%);background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(35,35,35,0.5) 0%, rgba(153,153,153,0) 80%);background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(35,35,35,0.5) 0%, rgba(153,153,153,0) 80%);background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(35,35,35,0.5) 0%,rgba(153,153,153,0) 80%);}
.panel-player .avatar img.teamLogo {display: block;filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=20);opacity: 0.2; background:none;}
.panel-player .playeroftheweek-name {font-family: NFLEndzoneTechBold, sans-serif; font-size:; line-height:; margin-bottom:0; color:#222;}
.panel-player .text .stat-value {font-family:NFLEndzoneTechBold, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; line-height:; letter-spacing:0px;margin-bottom:0; color:#666;}
.panel-player .text { padding:0px 10px;}

.panel-gir.potw>.panel-body { 
position: relative;
background: #fcfcfc;
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiA/Pgo8c3ZnIHhtbG5zPSJodâ€¦EiIGhlaWdodD0iMSIgZmlsbD0idXJsKCNncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkKSIgLz4KPC9zdmc+);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fcfcfc 0%, #f8f8f8 25%, #f3f3f3 44%, #f8f8f8 65%, #e8e8e8 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #fcfcfc), color-stop(25%, #f8f8f8), color-stop(44%, #f3f3f3), color-stop(65%, #f8f8f8), color-stop(100%, #e8e8e8));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fcfcfc 0%, #f8f8f8 25%, #f3f3f3 44%, #f8f8f8 65%, #e8e8e8 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fcfcfc 0%, #f8f8f8 25%, #f3f3f3 44%, #f8f8f8 65%, #e8e8e8 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fcfcfc 0%, #f8f8f8 25%, #f3f3f3 44%, #f8f8f8 65%, #e8e8e8 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fcfcfc 0%,#f8f8f8 25%,#f3f3f3 44%,#f8f8f8 65%,#e8e8e8 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#fcfcfc', endColorstr='#e8e8e8',GradientType=0 );
-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
-moz-border-radius: 4px;
-ms-border-radius: 4px;
-o-border-radius: 4px;
border-radius: 4px;
border: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
}

.panel-nfc.stats .hm-table-caption td { background:#000000!important;}


.injuryBox { font-weight:normal;}
```

Comment: One last thing, not as important, that is bugging me is the Standings. it displays the full team names instead of shortened versions, like BUF, so its making the table too wide, not everything fits right. Im not sure where I can put in code to change that. Buf for buffalo bills, IND for Indianopolis Colts, etc

Comment: Your code is incorrect in many instances. At the bottom of your header code you have a div end tag inside a style element that isn't inside a head element. I really recommend making your code more coherent and your problem will be easier to identify.

Answer (score 0):

The three columns are the div 's where the class is col-xs-3, col-xs-6, and col-xs-3. These classes set the width of the three columns. You have a section that isn't in any of the columns and is pushing your third column down. Specifically this section.

```
<div class="hmPortlet">
<div class="hmPortletDecoration">
<div class="hmPortletTitle" style="color:#ffffff;text-align:center">Around    The League</div>
</div>
<div class="hmPortletContent">
<div id="news-stream-container"></div>
</div>
</div><!--end of newswire portlet -->
```

Remove this section or put it inside of the one of the div sections with the classes mentioned before. As long as it and the rest of the sections have non-specific widths the columns should align correctly.

Comment: Thanks. Ill have to remove that portion and the Shoutbox as well. If I do that, everything looks fine.  Any idea about the Italic fonts all over the place? I dont see anything the specifies an Italic font.

Comment: Chrome debug says the source of the italic is User Agent Stylesheet. So I I think adding Normalize.css will fix that for you it has to do with browser defaults. Or you can just specify the style for those elements in css rather than letting the browser figure it out.

Comment: pardon my ignorance, but where do I add Normalize.css? I tried adding <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css"> to the Header but that did nothing. Im obviously doing it very wrong

Comment: For the life of me, I cant see why it still shows Italics. There is nothing in the code that mentions Italics.

Comment: It's showing italics because of browser defaults not because of any stylesheet you have created. You can override that by adding styles that overwrite the default. You might add the !important tag to ensure that it is over other styles .col-xs-3 p { font-style:normal !important; }

Comment: I actually found out the issue. This <i"> was in the wrong place in the League Header. I moved it from where it was and things are working fine now